# sed circular replacements

Tags: regex, sed

In my file input.txt, I want to replace A->B, B->C, and C->A
i.e. I want to run

```
s/A/B/g;
s/B/C/g;
s/C/A/g;
```

However, I don't want the patterns to operate on the new text
i.e. if I run the above sed script, A becomes unchanged A->B->C->A, and B goes to A (B->C->A)

Is there a way to do the replacements I want?

Thanks

Comment: What are A, B and C exactly? Characters or String?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a better way, but if there are suitable X and Y not in your input.txt you could try:

```
s/A/X/g;
s/B/Y/g;
s/C/A/g;
s/X/B/g;
s/Y/C/g;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `tr` : `tr 'ABC' 'BCA'`

Comment: I am not certain that OP literally means A, B or C characters. More probably strings.

Comment: @mouviciel: Yes, after second read, I think you're right. But I keep answer in case of.

Answer (score 0):

Use the y operator instead of the s operator:

```
sed y/ABC/BCA/
```

Answer (score 0):

We can complement the good bgg answer this way. Just append a newline to the strings to be used as `X` or `Y`. If we have this file:

```
$ cat teste.in 
ABC DEF GHI
GHI ABC DEE
DEF ABB ABCd
```

We execute this sed command:

```
$ sed 's/ABC/ABC\n/g 
s/DEF/DEF\n/g
s/GHI/ABC/g
s/ABC\n/DEF/g
s/DEF\n/GHI/g' teste.in
DEF GHI ABC
ABC DEF DEE
GHI ABB DEFd
```

Since it is very unlikely that a newline will appear in a line, it works. (Note that I used GNU sed. Some seds cannot accept the `\n` notation. In this case, just use a backslash followed by an actual newline:

```
$ sed 's/ABC/ABC\
/g 
s/DEF/DEF\
/g
s/GHI/ABC/g
s/ABC\
/DEF/g
s/DEF\
/GHI/g' teste.in
DEF GHI ABC
ABC DEF DEE
```

This should work.)